# jQuery mobile - how do I get rid of the blue highlight on the Home button

Tags: webkit, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm using jQuery mobile, and am using a home button in the header. When clicked, the home button has a blue highlight. I want to get rid of this, but can't seem to track down the CSS rule/-webkit CSS rule to do this.

Screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Unfortunately there haven't been enough acceptable answers to my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile the class added to buttons just pressed is: `ui-btn-active`. Here is a link to the documentation that talks about this class (although it doesn't say much): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Not sure if this is what you needed but I figured it might help. I'd recommend using FireBug or some such DOM Inspection tool to view the button in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You sure that's not just the default hi-light that links get when focused?

Try

```
#buttonID:focus{
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**An idea** to help you track the problem as you don't share the link (you can easily just share the first page), is to use **Safari**, **Chrome** or even **Firefox** and make them act as an iPhone so you can use their Inspector / Firebug to track the problem

**Firefox** has a [Agent User Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) that you can easily make use in order to the browser be intrepertate as an iPhone

[image]

**Chrome** [has it as well](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj) just add the User Agent string in the Extension options to create a new option

**Safari 5** is the easiest one as this is already built in:

1. Open Safari and go to the Preferences, move to Advanced. At the bottom of the tab there is a check box for `Show Develop menu in menu bar.`
2. Go to the `Develop` menu and move to `User Agent` and select any iOS device.